# Quantifier question?

Tags: quantifiers

How would I do the following quantifier and their negation

No one loves everybody.

or could you say : everybody does not love someone?

x is all people

So in symbolic this would be $\forall x, \exists y,$ x does not love y.

and the denial is

Someone loves everyone.

$\exists x,\forall y$, x loves y

My second ?

Everybody loves someone

$\forall x, \exists y$, x loves y

the denial

someone does not love everyone.

$\exists x, \forall y$, x does not love everyone.

Comment: Is your age really $93$?

Comment: That first one is a little off, I'd interpret that more as $\forall x$,$\exists y \ni x$ does not love $y$

Comment: Age is only a number fernando is still in his prime

Comment: @silynn: What does the $\ni$ do there?

Comment: Oh right, that's a really old notation... it's "such that"

Comment: Ah, odd. I've only seen that used in the context $x\ni\phi$ as a sort of alternative to $\{x:\phi\}$;I'm not sure reading $\ni$ as "such that" does anything here...

Comment: @FernandoMartinez: so You should say the secret of The elixir of youth :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first is correct. But the notation can be improved. Usually we use an uppercase letter to represent a set and a lower case letter to represent an element in the set.

So a better way to state is "Let $X$ be all people." Then your first statement is:

$\forall x \in X, \exists y \in X$, such that $x$ does not love $y$.

Similar for other statements.

However, the denial for the second statement is a little off. It should be:

someone does not love anyone

or equivalently

someone loves no one.

The quantifier for the denial would be

$\exists x \in X, \forall y \in X$, $x$ does not love $y$.

Comment: The use of a set and membership is totally optional for a single-sorted theory (and even a many-sorted theory can usually avoid it). Personally, I don't think it adds much, pedagogically.

Comment: @MaliceVidrine I agree. But it's confusing in the original post. Fernando used $x$ to represent all people and then used $\exists x$ in the quantifier to represent some person.

Comment: D'oh. Somehow I had totally missed that; in that case it sure does represent an improvement. (For the OP's benefit, it would also be well understood verbiage to say something like "let all variables range over the set of all people/yurts/people in yurts".)

Comment: I see thanks this makes sense